# Getting "Invalid secret key format" exception

Tags: keystore, dsa, jceks

I have two applications running on IBM JDK 8 and Open JDK 11 respectively, there is common module used in both the application. I have symmetric key used by both the application , symmetric key will be stored in keystore file so that i have used **JCEKS** as a keystore provider with DSA algorithm,

Now when first application runs (IBM JDK 8), keystore file created with symmetric key, Now when i run second application with Open JDK 11 ideally it should access that key generated by application running on IBM java 8.

But i am getting

```
Error:java.io.IOException: Invalid secret key format.
```

If i remove existing keystore file then if i run OpenJDK 11 application first, Its working fine.